# Excel - Edit Select columns by a common value

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a set of values, like this.

```
5   5   5   5   5   5
9   7   7   6   6   55
5   4   4   7   5   30
10  8   7   6   9   60
9   9   9   9   9   80
20  20  20  20  20  20
```

Lets say I want to edit all the values by -1, or +1, how would I do it? I'm pretty much new to this, and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Excel 2007.

Comment: What programming language? If you meant you want to do this using excel your in the wrong place. Try somewhere like superuser.

Comment: @Ash: I think Sharks wants to use VBA to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do this either in normal Excel or with VBA is to use Excel's `Paste Special` capability

**Manual Method**

- In a empty cell, enter -1 (or 1 for your second case)
- Copy that cell
- highlight your set of values
- Edit .... Paste Special .... Add to add that value to all the cells

A multiplication example of this technique is provided here from [Mr Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/paste-special-add-operation.php)

**VBA Method**

Code from [Zack Barresse](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=49) modified for xl07/10 that uses a blank cell in column A for the addition

```
Option Explicit
Sub psAdd()

Dim y As Integer    'The multiplier value, user-defined
Dim x As Range    'Just a blank cell for variable
Dim z As Range    'Selection to work with
Set z = Selection
y = Application.InputBox("Enter amount to add to selection:", _
                         Title:="Add to selection", Default:=10, Type:=1)
Set x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
If y = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Cancel button will = 0, hence cancel
If x <> "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else: x.Value = y
    x.Copy
    z.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd
    Application.CutCopyMode = False    'Kill copy mode
End If
x.ClearContents    'Back to normal : )
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, to open up the VBA editor try <kbd>Alt+F11</kbd>.

The code below shows one way of doing what you want.
Do not copy and paste it.
It's there to help get you started on your own code.

A quick explanation:

1. declare some variables,
2. use two `for` loops to iterate over a small range of cells,
3. increment each cell's value by 1.

**After** you have written your own code you should be able to run it by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
option explicit

sub increment_cell_values()
    dim r as long
    dim c as long
    dim ws as worksheet

    set ws = activesheet
        for r = 1 to 6
            for c = 1 to 6
                ws.cells(r,c).value = ws.cells(r,c).value + 1
            next c
        next r
    next ws
end sub
```